# What is messaging domain in JMS

Tags: java, jms

I am learning JMS from documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdr.html and came across this statement:

> The JMS API minimizes the set of concepts a programmer must learn in
>   order to use messaging products but provides enough features to
>   support sophisticated messaging applications. It also strives to
>   maximize the portability of JMS applications across JMS providers in
>   the same messaging domain.

I don't understand this. What are JMS providers and what is messaging domain here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMS providers are 3rd parties that provide implementations of the JMS specification such as IBMMQ & RabbitMQ.

The messaging domain in this case will be the processing of messages as determined by the JMS specification.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is old but people who come here searching for answer it helps, [here](http://kpsrawat.blogspot.in/2013/04/java-message-service-concepts.html)
good article explained nicely. To answer to the question "domain" is very generic in this context. to say in the world of messaging